# Tangent bundle of open annulus is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: tangent-bundle

I want to prove that the tangent bundle of open annulus is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^3$.

This arguments came from [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31690/examples-of-non-diffeomorphic-smooth-manifolds-with-diffeomorphic-tangent-bundle)

I have no clue of constructing this, any rudimental information will be helpful.

I have some basic information of constructing $T\mathbb{S}^1 $ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^1%$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result can be deduced from the following facts.

(1) The annulus is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times R^1$.

(2) The tangent bundle of $S^1$ is $S^1\times R^1$. See the following post: [Tangent bundle of $S^1$ is diffeomorphic to the cylinder $S^1\times\Bbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742121/tangent-bundle-of-s1-is-diffeomorphic-to-the-cylinder-s1-times-bbbr). The tangent bundle of $R^1$ is obviously $R^2$.

(3) The tangent bundle of a product manifold $M_1\times M_2$ is $TM_1\times TM_2$. Here $TM$ denotes the tangent bundle of $M$.